# Can't access class 'viewModel'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

Currently started to learn **MVVM Kotlin**. This youtube tutorial is pretty confusing but direct to the point.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LaUXQcGuT0&t=254s

I have this error in my title.

this code triggers the error in my `MainActivity`

[image]

So here's my `Module:app` (`build.gradle`)

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//Config data binding compiler with Kotlin
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.1'

//LifeCycle Extensions
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

//Toasty to show Toast
implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.8'
}
```

DataBinding

```
dataBinding{
    enabled=true
}
```

applied plugin

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

  apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt"

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

My `activity_main.xml`

```
<data>
    <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.ViewModel.LoginViewModel"/>
</data>
```

and Here's my File Structure of MVVM

[image]

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.View

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.Interface.LoginResultCallbacks
import com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.R
import com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.ViewModel.LoginViewModel 
import com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.ViewModel.LoginViewModelFactory
import com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LoginResultCallbacks {
override fun onSuccess(message: String) {
    Toasty.success(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show()
}

override fun onError(message: String) {
    Toasty.error(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    activityMainBinding.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginViewModelFactory(this))
        .get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
}
 }
```

I understand the process of MVVM but I don't know what is reason why this error keeps occuring. The tutorial of this MVVM is really helpful for understanding the mvvm kotlin that's why I'm pursuing to continue this app to make it work.

Comment: Please show us your mainActivity snippet code

Comment: I updated my question please see my MainActivity.kt

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue. Problem is in your type `type="com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.ViewModel.LoginViewModel"`
Remember in databinding only Viewmodel class name should start with Capital letter and other parent folder of a class should start with lower case. Just rename `ViewModel`with `viewModel`. Clear and Rebuild the project.

Comment: the package name should start with lowercase

Comment: exactly, all package name or you can say folder should start with lower case.

Comment: In my case my package name in small letter, but still showing issue

Answer (score 2):

Many people experience this because they have their packages named starting with a capital letter. Rename your package names to start with a small case letters such that in your path of reference to view Model class its only the view Model class that starts with a capital letter

i.e `type="com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.viewModel.LoginViewModel"`

solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply rename the package from `ViewModel` to `viewModel`. The first character just has to be lowercase and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

hey, i see you did not include this library

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
```

my dependencies
[image]

Have you try write code like below

```
activityMainBinding?.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,LoginViewFactory(this)).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
```

Because it needs nullable variable, but you assigned non-nulable variable

Comment: Tried it but not working on my side. Does my kotlin version and android studio matters? that's why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Kotlin in 1.3.31 is stable version. Have you update for newer?

Comment: I update my android studio to newer version and I'm using `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31' ext.gradle_version = '3.0.1'`

Comment: have you include this library     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'

Comment: also i recommend you to migrate all dependecy to jetpack (androidx). Because in my project, i didnt get wrong with same dependencies (jetpack)

Comment: I tried to include the implementation part still getting the error. Hmm can u link me to the dependencies that you are referring to me?

Comment: like this: [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started) . I also will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the package name that you're using for your view model classes
Although google call this structural design pattern "MVVM" and everybody want to make "Model", "ViewModel" and "View" packages in their project, but when data-binding library wants to generate the files for you will confront problem with package names.
So you just need to change the destination name of :

```
import com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.ViewModel.LoginViewModel
```

to :

```
import com.example.rnd.kotlinmvvmlogin.data.LoginViewModel
```

or anything else.
Also you may want to change "View" to "ui" so it don't cause problem for later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's quite unfortunate, even though it is referred to as a MVVM architecture, you can't have a package named "ViewModel", "ViewModels", "viewModels", or in any case similar to the sort, or else it just won't build, and it gives you a completely misleading error.

Comment: You can use 'viewModels' as the package name. Only the first letter of the package name has to be lowercase for it to work.